# Finding POS-TAG Frequency in sentences of a corpus

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, data-analysis, pos-tagger

Q. Finding pos-tag frequency/ sentence. Forgive me I am new to python started about 4 months ago. I was able to figure out how to apply pos-tags to the words in the document.

```
        train_text = SOME TEXT 1
        sample_text = SOME TEXT 2

        custom_sent_tokenizer = PunktSentenceTokenizer(train_text)

        tokenized = custom_sent_tokenizer.tokenize(sample_text)

def process_content():
    try:
       for i in tokenized:
          words = nltk.word_tokenize(i)
          tagged = nltk.pos_tag(words)
          print(tagged)

    except Exception as e:
      print(str(e))
 process_content()
```

Now here is where I have no idea to proceed. At this point I am interested in calculating the frequency of certain POS_TAGs per sentence. Then when I do that, I want to plot the sentence length (number of words) in relation to the number of the POS-TAGs I identified. When I tried to do this I was only able to find the frequency of the post-tags in the whole document in relation to all the words in the document. Even though I tokenized already I am still getting the whole document when I analyze. Help this is driving my nuts!

Comment: The code you are showing isn't concerned with counting the tags, so there's no way to help you like this.

Comment: Sounds like you need to group your sentences according to length, and calculate your statistics separately for each group. Or maybe not; there's no way to guess what you really want.

Comment: Hi, what I precisely want to do is find how many times the target pos-tag appears per sentence, divide that number by the number of words in the sentence. Then do this for all the sentences. Add up this stuff and divide by the number of sentences in the text.